# js-cookie value is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, js-cookie

I am trying to get the string "value" from the cookie "name" however, 'undefined' is always printing out. 
I am using chrome and any help would be appreciated

Here is my code:

```
Cookies.set('name', 'value');
var plswork = Cookies.get('name');
document.write(plswork);
```

Comment: Can you tell us what `Cookies` is please

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript possibly duplicate

Comment: ... and `Cookies` is what? I'm assuming it's a class that you or a 3rd party has created. And as you have not added a `php` or `node-js` tag on the question, you will likely actually be attempting to use `localStorage` on the client: Take a read of this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage

Comment: Are you using js-cookie (https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)?  If so, looks right to me.  https://jsfiddle.net/simpsond/c3g28cmo/

Answer (score -1):

Cookies are stored in the "document.cookie" JavaScript object

```
var a = document.cookie; 
document.write();
```