# JS-Cookie always returns undefined

Tags: javascript, cookies

Hello I'm stuck with a situation and I'm not capable to get [JS-Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) v2.1.3 working as expected.
I'm thinking that there is some browser issues involved on this point, but I can't determine it exactly so I wish someboduy could give some light
My goal is to set up a language cookie on my site, I have the following code:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $('#botEn').click(function(e) {
      Cookies.set('idioma', 'en', {
        expires: 7,
        path: '/'
      });
      $('.alert').html('<p>Btn english >> cookie:'+Cookies.get('idioma')+'</p>');

    });

    $('#botEs').click(function(e) {
      Cookies.set('idioma', 'es', {
        expires: 7,
        path: '/'
      });
      $('.alert').html('<p>Btn español >> cookie:'+Cookies.get('idioma')+'</p>');
    });

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/faridsilva/vrqvLfk2/18/

[image: Mi fiddle showing the issue]

This code only works in chrome (my version is 56.0.2924.87 64-bit), but firefox 51.x and safari 10.x always returns "undefined"

The same happens to me with Dustin Simpson example in [his fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/simpsond/c3g28cmo/) which he says is working fine as reply to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35609529/js-cookie-value-is-undefined).

[image: Dustin Simpson fiddle]

Comment: I came across this answer is my search for solution to scenario where `Cookies.get()` was always returning `undefined` - if it helps anyone, I was developing locally and I don't think Cookies works in local environment, on live site it works as expected.  See:  https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/issues/281

Comment: I  my case the reason why i couldnt access the cookie was that it was created on server and was secure. Since i could not read the cookie value, i needed to do the logic at serverside and pass the information i needed not via cookie.